# Boost C++ on Windows IOT Core

Tags: c++, windows, boost, arm, iot

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 with Universal Windows Project to build it on RaspberryPi 2 (ARM). For my program I need to use the Boost C++ Libraries, is this libraries compatible with Win10 IoT Core ? At the same time, I've linked Boost to Visual Studio 2015 but I've an error when cross-compiling : "LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_regex-vc140-mt-gd-1_63.lib'"

Need help please.

Thanks,

Azm0g.

Answer (score 1):

The linking error message shows you're trying to reference the the wrong library format(x86 or x64) for your Windows ARM project.

You should be reference the arm build binaries for your Windows IoT project.

Since boost does [NOT](https://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost-binaries/) provide pre-built binaries for Windows ARM yet, meaning it's not yet officially supported.

I also found a nice [tutorial](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2014/07/18/using-boost-libraries-in-windows-store-and-phone-applications/) on how to compile the boost library targeting ARM with Windows Phone, you may try it yourself.

Notice that not all Win32 APIs are available on UWP, even you're able to build it successfully, you may not have access to all the boost modules nontherless.